# How do I add an addition statement at the end of a Println statement, inside of a Case statement?

Tags: java

For context, I'm working on a school project that needs me to print out every line from The 12 Days of Christmas with only writing each line once. I've got it down I just need to find a way to add a number at the end of each case to make it print the next case.

A snippet of my code:

```
switch (DayOfChristmas) {
   case 1 -> System.out.println(OnThe+"1st"+DayOfChris+"\n"+ChrisDay1);
```

output:

```
On the 1st day of Christmas, my true love gave to me, 
A Partridge in a pear tree.
```

There are other cases after this and I need to know how to add 1 to the int DayOfChristmas so it will print the next case after printing the first.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a for loop like so:

```
for(int i = 0; i <=12; i++){
    //Your Switch Statement Here
    switch(i){
        case 1 -> System.out.println("On the "+i+" day of Christmas"...)
    }
}
```

The `for` loop starts with integer `i` set to 0. It checks whether `i` is smaller or equal to `12`. If it is, then it will execute the code within the loop, then add 1 to `i`.